# SSL certs on Windows and Linux

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create certification to enable HTTPS for our company's domain. It should work on both Windows and Linux system.

I know on Linux, I need to start from openssl .key file, to .csr file, finally to .crt file, then configure the apache server.

Will Windows instance using the same key files? Or Windows should have its own certification file format, such as .p7b, .pem, .cer files?

Confused here.. Which file should I create first if I want it work on both Windows and Linux systems?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a pfx file from your crt and key file in this way:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domainname.pfx -inkey domainname.key -in domainname.crt
```

Then, use this pfx on windows.

Comment: Cool, this is what I want!